# "No return tag" error found in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: hreflang

I have set hreflang tag on my web pages but the error is not fixed.  I have set following tag in each web pages by dynamically:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.sumolounge.ca/" hreflang="en-ca" />
```

Still have problem as it is.  We have four different domain but language is used in same (English).

- https://www.sumolounge.ca/
- https://www.sumolounge.com/

Answer (score -1):

I do not see any hreflang tags on either of these pages. Also, if you have the exact same content, then don't put it on multiple sites. Only use hreflang and multiple sites if you are truly localizing the content for each market.

Comment: The exact same content on sites meant for audiences in two different countries is absolutely fine for SEO.   It can actually work better for Google rankings that way.

Comment: I also see where in the source code there is a hreflang.   It appears they are trying to insert it with JavaScript:  `$("head").append("<link rel='alternate' href='"+window.location.href+"' hreflang='en-ca' />");`